# What this kind of office space called, opposed to another one where each one has their own office?

Tags: word-usage

This image shows a type of office space, where lots of people could see and touch each other easily.

[image]

opposed to which, another one is where each one has their own office with a closed door at most of the time.

What are those two type of office space called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Wikpedia "open plan"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_plan)

"Open plan is the generic term used in architectural and interior design for any floor plan which makes use of large, open spaces..."

This may be contrasted to "cubicles" or individual offices.